# how to use multiple elements, multiple events, but same function in an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have:

if (event X happens on element A)
  execute Code R

if (event Y happens on element B)
  execute Code R

In jQuery, instead of the 2 if statements, how do you have 1 if statement whereby:

if (event X happens on element A) OR (event Y happens on element B)
  execute Code R

I've been looking at bind methods but haven't been able to  find the solution to this. It's like Google's search function: If you click on the 'search' button, it executes the search. However, if you type something in the input box and press the 'enter' key, it also executes the search. Again, two different elements (button and input box), two different events (mouse click and key press), but same function (search)?

Answer (score 3):

There won't be any `if` statements in your final code. You have to bind the event handler for each event to each element, and the event handler can of course be the same function:

```
function event_handler() {
    // ...
}

$(elementA).on('eventX', event_handler);
$(elementB).on('eventY', event_handler);
```

I recommend to read the jQuery tutorials: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials.

To learn more about event handling in general, have a look at these articles: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the same function to both event / element combinations:

```
$('#elementA').on('click', myEventHandler);
// You can specify multiple Events:
$('#elementB').on('mousedown mouseup blur', myEventHandler);
// Or specify multiple elements:
$('#elementB, #elementC').on('click', myEventHandler);

function myEventHandler(e){
    console.log(e.type); // Event type ('mousedown', 'mouseup' etc)
    console.log(this);  // The element that triggered the event.
    // Do stuff.
}
```

But you can't bind `click` to `'#elementA'` **and** `mousedown` to `'#elementB'` in 1 line.

So, no, there is no "One-liner" jQuery function to bind multiple ***different*** events to ***different*** elements.

Basically, [Have a look at jQuery's `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Why do you say that? `$('#selector1, #selector2')` selects both elements, and `.bind('event1 event2', handler)` binds the handler to both events.

Comment: @MihaiStancu: added some clarification

Comment: OK, that makes more sense, indeed no one-liners like that AFAIK. You can use the code I provided and add some logic (`if`/`switch`) to check the type of object that created the event (`e.target`) and the type of event (`e.type`) and decide what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple jQuery selectors separated by commas (like CSS selectors). The resulting jQuery object list will contain all of them.

Binding multiple events in jQuery is allowed if you use `.bind()` or `.on()` and set the first parameter to be a list of event names separated by spaces.

```
function handler_function (e) {
    e.target // contains the element that triggered the event (which was clicked for ex.)
    e.type // contains the event type that triggered the event
    e.keyCode // contains a number representing the key that has been pressed (if any)
}
$('button#button_id, input[type=text]#input_box')
    .bind('keyup click hover touch drag drop', handler_function);
```

Comment: Oh, in jQuery's event handlers, you should be able to use `this` instead of `e.target`.

Comment: Yeah, but it's important to study the `event` object so I promote it more often.

Comment: @Cerbrus are there any circumstances in which `this` may not be attached to any object? Or may be attached nonintuitively? I think the `mousemove` event attaches it to the `body` object.

Comment: I usually use native JS, so, no clue, I'm afraid.
**Edit:** Actually: `$('#answer-14140858').on('mousemove', function(){console.log(this)})` Logged your answer, not the `body` object.